# Bundling an AMI out of a running ec2 instance fails

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm trying to create my own AMI based upon a 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10 EBS AMI. However, the commands fails as seen below. I've googled for this specific error and have drawn a blank.

Can someone help here?

```
    $ sudo ec2-bundle-vol -u XXXXXXX -c foo.pem -k bar.pem -d /persistent/ami/2012-02-02-0634/

    Please specify a value for arch [x86_64]: 
    Copying / into the image file /persistent/ami/2012-02-02-0634/image...
    Excluding: 
             /var/www
             /sys/kernel/debug
             /sys/kernel/security
             /sys
             /var/log/mysql
             /var/lib/mysql
             /
             /proc
             /etc/apache2
             /etc/mysql
             /sys/fs/fuse/connections
             /dev/pts
             /dev
             /etc/php5
             /var/lib/php5
             /dev
             /media
             /mnt
             /proc
             /sys
             /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
             /etc/udev/rules.d/z25_persistent-net.rules
             /persistent/ami/2012-02-02-0634/image
             /mnt/img-mnt
    1+0 records in
    1+0 records out
    1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00215727 s, 486 MB/s
    mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
    loop: can't delete device /dev/loop0: No such device or address
    ERROR: execution failed: "rsync -rlpgoD -t -r -S -l --exclude /var/www --exclude /sys/kernel/debug --exclude /sys/kernel/security --exclude /sys --exclude /var/log/mysql --exclude /var/lib/mysql --exclude / --exclude /proc --exclude /etc/apache2 --exclude /etc/mysql --exclude /sys/fs/fuse/connections --exclude /dev/pts --exclude /dev --exclude /etc/php5 --exclude /var/lib/php5 --exclude /dev --exclude /media --exclude /mnt --exclude /proc --exclude /sys --exclude /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules --exclude /etc/udev/rules.d/z25_persistent-net.rules --exclude /persistent/ami/2012-02-02-0634/image --exclude /mnt/img-mnt -X /* /mnt/img-mnt 2>&1 > /dev/null"
```

Answer (score 4):

For an [Amazon EBS-Backed Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Concepts_BootFromEBS.html) it is nowadays much simpler (and thus recommended) to facilitate the single dedicated API call [ec2-create-image](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html) instead of *ec2-bundle-vol*, which can alternatively and conveniently done via the AWS Management Console as well, as outlined in [Creating an Image from a Running Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Tutorial_CreateImage.html) - please be aware that by default EC2 *attempts to cleanly shut down the instance before image creation and reboots the instance afterwards*.

This is obviously generally preferable, however, it can be avoided via the command line indeed, if so desired:

> If you prefer the instance not be rebooted, you can use the Amazon EC2
>   command line tools to create the image [...]. The [ec2-create-image](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html) command has a --no-reboot option.

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting. But is ec2-create-image smart enough to exclude certain directories like ec2-bundle-vol ? I'll have to wait to try it out since my running instance is already in production and I can't shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

Point here to have an AMI without rebooting/shuting down your instance: https://serverfault.com/questions/324891/how-to-create-an-amazon-ami-from-a-running-ubuntu-instance-without-booting-via

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution was really simple... `rsync` was not installed on my machine...